# restaurar base de datos en postgresql toma mucho tiempo

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

Tengo el siguiente problema. 
Genero el .backup de mi base de datos que pesa 210 megas. Cuando restauro desde el pgadmin 3 se demora una eternidad (toca dejarla toda una tarde o toda una noche). Inclusive la he restaurado desde consola pensando que el pgadmin me retrasaba la restaurada, pero no, es igual de demorada.
La base de datos tiene 1745 tablas y mucha información, está montada en un servidor con 16 GB de ram.
Quisiera saber si hay algún método para poder restaurar la base de datos más rápido, o esa demora es normal para una base de datos de estas dimensiones.
Muchas gracias

Comment: Para restaurar la base de datos, ¿lo haces desde algún cliente gráfico o directo en consola?

Comment: si claro, es desde el pgadmin 3